# HeatMap da API do Google

Tags: javascript, api, google

Estava trabalhando num projeto que envolve pegar coordenadas (lat e long) e usá-las pra criar um Mapa com marcadores (que esta funcionando) e um HeatMap(que é o foco do problema). Usei um exemplo [deste link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap?hl=pt-br) e adaptei ao meu escopo... Mas não funciona. Não apresenta erros mas o mapa simplesmente não carrega, segue o código do meu JVS:

```
var map;
var infoWindow;

// A variável markersData guarda a informação necessária a cada marcador
// Para utilizar este código basta alterar a informação contida nesta variável
var markersData = new Array();

//GET JSON OCORRENCIAS
$.getJSON( "https://webserver-nao-vacila.herokuapp.com/ocorrencia/?format=json", function( data ) {
    markersData = data;
    // Chamada para a função que vai percorrer a informação
    // contida na variável markersData e criar os marcadores a mostrar no mapa
    displayMarkers();
    createHeatMap();
})


function initialize() {
   var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.017655, -34.944377),
      zoom: 9,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

   // cria a nova Info Window com referência à variável infowindow
   // o conteúdo da Info Window será atribuído mais tarde
   infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   // evento que fecha a infoWindow com click no mapa
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.close();
   });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// Esta função vai percorrer a informação contida na variável markersData
// e cria os marcadores através da função createMarker
function displayMarkers(){

    // esta variável vai definir a área de mapa a abranger e o nível do zoom
    // de acordo com as posições dos marcadores
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Loop que vai estruturar a informação contida em markersData
    // para que a função createMarker possa criar os marcadores
    for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].latitude, markersData[i].longitude);
        var titulo = markersData[i].titulo;
        var data = markersData[i].data;
        var endereco = markersData[i].endereco;

        createMarker(latlng, titulo, data, endereco);

        // Os valores de latitude e longitude do marcador são adicionados à
        // variável bounds
        bounds.extend(latlng);
    }

    // Depois de criados todos os marcadores
    // a API através da sua função fitBounds vai redefinir o nível do zoom
    // e consequentemente a área do mapa abrangida.
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Função que cria os marcadores e define o conteúdo de cada Info Window.
function createMarker(latlng, titulo, data, endereco){
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: latlng,
      title: titulo
   });

   // Evento que dá instrução à API para estar alerta ao click no marcador.
   // Define o conteúdo e abre a Info Window.
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

      // Variável que define a estrutura do HTML a inserir na Info Window.
      var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' +
            '<div class="iw_title">' + titulo + '</div>' +
         '<div class="iw_content">' + data + '<br />' +
         endereco + '<br />' + '</div></div>';

      // O conteúdo da variável iwContent é inserido na Info Window.
      infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);

      // A Info Window é aberta.
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
   });
}

// Função que cria o mapa de calor
function createHeatMap(){

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].latitude, markersData[i].longitude);
    }
    bounds.extend(latlng)
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: markersData
    });
    heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : markersData);


    map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
```

Creio que só o JVS apresente "problema" mas se precisar de mais partes do código to disposto a mostrar aqui.

Comment: Ele dá algum tipo de erro, creio que você vai ter que dar mais detalhes pra gente aqui

Comment: Eu tentei uma nova implementação, bem mais simples.

function createHeatMap(){
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: markersData,
        map: map
    });
}

createHeatMap();

Comment: O único erro que apresenta, agora é este: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'HeatmapLayer' of undefined

Comment: Só que eu estou usando a chave do google que ele requer pra vc usar a API deles. No exemplo que eles dão no site, eu copiei e colei, usando uma chave e ele rodou tranquilamente...